# Is it possible to manually call onCreateView in a Fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, android-view, fragment-tab-host

Is it possible to manually call the method `onCreateView` in a `Fragment` or, if not, is there some way I can simulate this invocation?

I have a `FragmentActivity` with tabHost. Each tab contains a `Fragment` and I want to refresh the `Fragment`'s view when I press the "Refresh" button. More specifically, I want to re-call the `onCreateView` method.

My code currently looks like:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hall, container, false);

    layoutExsternal = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layoutExsternal);
    layoutHall = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layoutHall);

    init();

    return view;
 }

  [...]

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Log.d("itemSelected1", this.getClass().getSimpleName());

     switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_refresh:

            //HERE I want to insert a method for refresh o redraw

     return true;
     }

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

Comment: A better approach would be to refactor your onCreateView.  First find your layout views and assign them to fields, then call a delegate method that populates them.  Then have your refresh action call the delegate.  

You seem to already have this with your init() method.  Can't refresh just call that?

Comment: I find this approach useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/41888950/3496570

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have resolved my question. I replace the current fragment with itself, but before I have saved a reference of current fragment and then i close life cycle of current fragment invoking onDestroy(). I recall it with "newFragment" variable.

`switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_refresh:
         //THIS IS THE CODE TO REFRESH THE FRAGMENT.
             FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
             FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
             Fragment newFragment = this;
             this.onDestroy();
             ft.remove(this);
             ft.replace(container.getId(),newFragment);
              //container is the ViewGroup of current fragment
             ft.addToBackStack(null);   
             ft.commit();

        return true;
    }`

Comment: Manually calling lifecycle methods is never the right solution. Also you don't need the `newFragment` variable; you could just use `this` again.

Comment: As @Karu says, manually calling lifecycle methods is not a good approach.

Answer (score 35):

Sometimes I found FragmentTransaction's replace would not work for replacing a fragment with itself, what does work for me is using detach and attach:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .detach(fragment)
    .attach(fragment)
    .commit();
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156406/whats-the-difference-between-detaching-a-fragment-and-removing-it) for the difference between remove and detach

Comment: I used it in `onActivityResult` (coming back from settings where layout-affecting options may have changed) where I needed `commitAllowingStateLoss` because "You will receive this call immediately before `onResume()` when your activity is re-starting.". Calling `commit` would cause "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState". **Fragment state is still PRESERVED!**

Comment: Use .commitAllowingStateLoss() instead!

Answer (score 3):

You can just have your replace button replace the current layout with a new instance of the fragment.

```
// onButtonClick
SomeFragment fragment = new SomeFragment();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.current_layout, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: Isn't there a `commit` missing?