# How do I refresh an Activity that does not extend an Activity class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I found that to refresh an activity you do,
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());

However this is possible only if my present class extends Activity class. But my present class extends Fragment class, so how to I refresh it?.

I tried to pass the object of Intent from my MainActivity.java to this class via the constructor but then I was not able to call finish() that way.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207562/is-it-possible-to-manually-call-oncreateview-in-a-fragment

Comment: Do you need to refresh the activity or only the fragment's content?

Comment: I want to refresh only the fragment's content.

Answer (score 0):

Try use FragmentTransaction. Replace a fragment with itself, what does work for me is using detach and attach:

`getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .detach(fragment)
    .attach(fragment)
    .commit();`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass this object(Context) of the Activity to the class and call `finish()` + `startActivity()` on that.
From `MainActivity.java` pass this object and hold in your class as an Activity object and call `finish()` + `startActivity()` methods on this.