# Refresh a fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Earlier this code was working but it now it suddenly stopped working. Fragment is not detaching from parent activity.

```
public void reLoadFragment(Fragment fragment)
{
    Log.i(LogGeneratorHelper.INFO_TAG, "reloading fragment");
    // Reload current fragment
    Fragment frg = null;
    frg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragment.getClass().getName());
    frg.onDetach();
    final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.detach(frg);
    ft.attach(frg);
    ft.commit();
    Log.i(LogGeneratorHelper.INFO_TAG, "reloading fragment finish");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`ft.detach()` not working after support library update 25.1.0. This solution works fine after update:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(oldFragment).commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().attach(oldFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Credit:
[Refresh or force redraw the fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262747/refresh-or-force-redraw-the-fragment)

Comment: This worked for me in refreshing current fragment. None of the above answers worked in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Use this in yout Main Activity:

```
frag_name frag_name = new frag_name();
                    FragmentManager manager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.youtframelayout, frag_name, frag_name.getTag()).commit();
```

It inicializes the `fragment` and replaces it in your `FrameLayout`

Like this your replacing again the fragment :)

Hope it works! :)

Comment: thanks, i made it work like this.
ft.detach() not working after support library update 25.1.0. This solution works fine after update:

getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .detach(oldFragment)
    .commitNowAllowingStateLoss();

getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .attach(oldFragment)
    .commitAllowingStateLoss();

Answer (score 2):

You can simply refresh the current fragment using

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
```

Also, in your case you can do something like this,

```
public void reLoadFragment(Fragment fragment)
{
    Log.i(LogGeneratorHelper.INFO_TAG, "reloading fragment");
    Fragment currentFragment = fragment;
    if (currentFragment instanceof "FRAGMENT CLASS NAME") {
        FragmentTransaction fragTransaction =   (getActivity()).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
        fragTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
        fragTransaction.commit();
        Log.i(LogGeneratorHelper.INFO_TAG, "reloading fragment finish");
    }
    else Log.i(LogGeneratorHelper.INFO_TAG, "fragment reloading failed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will refresh current fragment :

```
  FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

**For kotlin use below code.**

```
 fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

For kotlin:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(fragment).attach(fragment).commit()
```