# HOW do you invalidate a fragment view?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-view-invalidate

Alright, so I have a fragment that displays user account information.

The way this works is it issues a request that may or may not touch the server, depending on what information is already cached.

When the information is available, there's a callback in which the fragment will update its textfields.

At that point, however, the UI needs be refreshed, so I'd like to issue some kind of `invalidate`...

Except that does perfectly nothing.

First, I noticed that `this.view` returns `null`. So rather than rely on that, I store the view I create in `onCreateView` explicitly.

Then after I updated the textfields, I call `fragmentView.postInvalidate()` ... which does nothing.

I also tried `doAsync { uiThread { fragmentView.invalidate() } }` ... which also does nothing.

Then I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41279916/3322533) and tried

```
    val fragment = this
    doAsync { uiThread {
        activity!!.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(fragment).commit()
        activity!!.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().attach(fragment).commit()
    }}
```

... which is even WORSE than not doing anything, because the other two ways will at least update the view if you switch to a different fragment and back, whereas this will perpetually refuse to display any useful information.

So maybe I can "cheat" by delaying the call to `super::setUserVisibleHint` until after I updated the values ... no, I can't.

What I ***can*** do, though, is I can force a redraw of the ui by toasting something. So that's what I am currently doing. But still, that can't be the solution.

How do I get a proper ui refresh?

Oh, and this is an `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and I'm using an `android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to switch between fragments, if that matters.

Full fragment code:

```
class AccountFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var fragmentView: View

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false)
        /*for some reason [this.view] remains null when we later try to use it, so we're explicitly storing a reference*/
        fragmentView = view
        return view
    }

    override fun setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser: Boolean) {
        if(isVisibleToUser)setAccountInformation()
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser)
    }

    private fun setAccountInformation(){
        val um = DataConfig.getUserManager()
        val au = um.getActiveUser()

        um.getUserInfo(au, Callback(
                onResponse = {when(it){
                    is SuccessfulAccountGetResponse -> {
                        val info = it.result

                        usernameText.text = info.name
                        uuidText.text = info.uuid
                        adminText.text = if(info.isAdmin) "YES" else "NO"

                        createdText.text = info.created.toString()
                        lastLoginText.text = info.lastLogin?.toString() ?: "-"

                        //now actually force the new information to show up
                        refreshUI()
                    }
                    else -> doAsync { uiThread{ activity?.longToast("could not get information") } }
                }},
                onError = {doAsync { uiThread { activity?.longToast("error: $it") } }}
        ))
    }

    /** forces a refresh, making changes visible*/
    private fun refreshUI(){
        /*hack: force a redraw by toasting */
        doAsync { uiThread { activity?.toast("updating values") } }

        //THIS does absolutely nothing: //TODO: figure out why
//        fragmentView.postInvalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling a `textView.setText(newText)` *should and does* invoke `invalidate()` on its own (possibly also `requestLayout()` in certain cases which invokes `invalidate()`), so you shouldn't need to manually call `postInvalidate()` unless you are custom-rendering with a Canvas.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce well, my fragments apparently didn't get the memo.

Comment: I think they are not getting `setUserVisibilityHint`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yes they are ... otherwise there would never BE a toast at all.